# How can I retrieve source code of Node js which is compiled into binary through jxCore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jxcore

I was working on Node Js project for a specific client. I was thinking that  I should encrypt this source code before delivering it to client. Then i came to know about JxCore.

**JXcore which is an open source project, introduces a unique feature for packaging and encryption of source files and other assets into JX packages.**

Then I followed these steps:

- Download JxCore using curl http://jxcore.com/xi.sh | bash
- Then I go to my project where app.js was my main entry file and execute this command: **jx package app.js encryptedApp**
- At the end i used this command to execute the project : **jx encryptedApp.jx**
- And then I got these two main files **1: encryptedApp.jx 2:encryptedApp.jxp**

**So Now my major concern is, Can I retrieve this source code of my project which is compiled into binary ?**

Comment: May I quite-honestly suggest to you that it is _not_ really worth your time to "encrypt <<anything>> before delivering it to your client?"  It greatly adds to the complexity of what you're doing (which, BTW, translates to _costs_ to your client ...), and it provides no real "protection" nor "job security" to you.  Instead, focus your attention on "keeping your client 150%-happy at all times."  (I've been in this crazy business for more than thirty-five years now, and this maxim has never failed me yet.)  **Trust** the hands that feed you!

Comment: Regarding the security - or lack thereof - of JXcore: https://markhaa.se/cracking-jxcore-again.html